# Is there a way to always find witch huts

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been searching for ages in my swamp, but I can't find a witch hut and I don't know how how to build one.

Does anyone know of a surefire(100% acurate) way to find witch huts?

Answer (score 6):

Where witch huts are placed depends on your world seed.
You can find out the seed by typing `/seed` in the console.

To find the witch hut, you can either calculate the coordinates by hand (too complicated); or use an tool like [**AMIDST**](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/626786-v36-amidst-strongholds-village-biome-etc-finder-174/):

[image: Finding witch huts with AMIDST]

The turquoise biome is a swamp, and the purple icons are witch huts (marked with red borders in my image), the house icon is the world spawn. You can find out coordinates of a place by hovering over it with the mouse; the coordinates will be shown at the top right.

If you are looking for a seed with multiple which huts at the same place, you might want to check out this thread: [Quad Witch Huts](http://hypixel.net/threads/quad-witch-huts-rarest-and-greatest-seed-ever.765/)

For building an witch hut I would recommend this tutorial: [YouTube Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KllWkdfOS3M)

Comment: I do have AMIDST and I do know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a 100% sure way because huts are spawned in at random. Also, you cannot build one either.  The spawning space that actually spawns the witches are in a hut within a 5x5x4 dimension but don't take my word.

Comment: did you know that if you start a world on peaceful difficulty and change to easy, normal or hard later on, if you find a witch hut, there will be no witch as the witches fromwitch huts are spawned during world generation. So that is a good way to take a witch hut as your home without having to fear and fight the witch.

Comment: @HugoDodd World generation is actually done continuously as you move around, not all at once when you create the world, so starting on Peaceful only influences the initial chunks, not chunks generated later on a harder difficulty. You may actually have been experiencing a known bug with witches not spawning in *any* houses in certain versions; it's not due to starting on peaceful.